# Display JSON object keys in the same order as in the YAML source

Tags: json, go, yaml

I'm working with the library `github.com/ghodss/yaml` to create JSON based in .yaml files, I'm experiencing that the JSON is not being displayed in the correct order as I have it.

This is my .yaml file:

```
name: "Foo"
lastname: "Bar"
age: 25
```

and this is my GoCode:

```
for _, file := range yamlfiles {

    yamlBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)

    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }

    jsonFormat, err := yaml.YAMLToJSON(yamlBytes)

    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(jsonFormat))
}
```

And this is the output:

```
{"age":25,"lastname":"Bar","name":"Foo"}
```

Expected output:

```
{"name":"Foo","lastname":"Bar","age":25}
```

How could I have this in order as I have my .yaml file?

Comment: The YAMLToJSON  function use the encoding/json [Marshal](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Marshal) function to generate the JSON.  This function sorts the keys as described in the documentation.

Comment: @ThunderCat thanks, that's good to know.

Comment: This is my first time using JSON, order could affect in future? or wouldn't matter?

Answer (score 2):

Your data consist of a single (root-level) mapping and the [YAML specification](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2762320) explicitly states:

> mapping - an unordered association of unique keys to values

A library compliant to the specification loads that mapping in an unordered way as so does your Go YAML-library.¹

*So your expectation is definitely incorrect.*

It could be coincidence, but it looks like your JSON is sorted by key, and that is a valid option given unsorted input.

---

¹ <sub>The only library that I know not to comply with this is ruamel.yaml for Python when using round-trip mode. Using Python and `ruamel.yaml` it is fairly trivial to get the output the way you expected.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you define a struct with those properties then the JSON marshaler will emit keys in the order that the fields were defined ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/NyvnRKRCjVS)):

```
type Person struct {
  Name     string `json:"name"`
  LastName string `json:"lastname"`
  Age      int    `json:"age"`
}

p := Person{"Foo", "Bar", 25}
bs, err := json.Marshal(&p)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(string(bs))
// {"name":"Foo","lastname":"Bar","age":25}
```